# How to make in wordpress a gallery with 3 colums to 1 on mobile devices responsive?

Tags: gallery, mobile, responsive, sitemap

After taking a lot of time researching websites I ask for help in this forum.

Im looking to have a gallery on the website like this:

[decañamo.site](https://www.deca%C3%B1amo.site/)

When the webpage is open it goes from the 3 products in a line to one.

Does someone have some info on how can reach this?

Thanks in advance for any info.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap grid system .
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Comment: Can you please edit your answer and add more details? Thanks.